# AWS - how to pass a service link role to an autoscaling group using CDK/CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, autoscaling, aws-cdk

Does anyone know how to pass a service linked role (autoscaling role with a suffix) to an autoscaling group by using CDK/CloudFormation?

I have managed to grant the default autoscaling service role access to a CMK living in another account. However, I don't want all autoscaling groups having the default role to have access to the key.

I assume that the best solution is to bootstrap the service linked role and grant it CMK access, but how do I pass the role? (This is not the instance assumable role)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  service linked role for Autoscaling is specified using [ServiceLinkedRoleARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-autoscaling-autoscalinggroup-servicelinkedrolearn) in `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`. It is not related to instance assumed role.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. I figured out that I could also [modify the AWS CloudFormation resource behind AWS constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html) in CDK by using autoscalingGroup.node.defaultChild as autoscaling.CfnAutoScalingGroup instead of the bucket.